# How does the catch keyword determine the type of exception that was thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

How does the `catch` keyword determine the type of exception that was thrown? What process occurs to select which catch block to execute?

```
try
{
    int[] myArray = new int[0];
    myArray[1] = 0;
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex) { } // how does the CLR know to enter here?
catch (InvalidCastException ex) { }
```

Via ILdasm

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       28 (0x1c)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init (int32[] V_0,
           class [mscorlib]System.IndexOutOfRangeException V_1,
           class [mscorlib]System.InvalidCastException V_2)
  IL_0000:  nop
  .try
  {
    IL_0001:  nop
    IL_0002:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0003:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_0008:  stloc.0
    IL_0009:  ldloc.0
    IL_000a:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_000b:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_000c:  stelem.i4
    IL_000d:  nop
    IL_000e:  leave.s    IL_001a
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.IndexOutOfRangeException 
  {
    IL_0010:  stloc.1
    IL_0011:  nop
    IL_0012:  nop
    IL_0013:  leave.s    IL_001a
  }  // end handler
  catch [mscorlib]System.InvalidCastException 
  {
    IL_0015:  stloc.2
    IL_0016:  nop
    IL_0017:  nop
    IL_0018:  leave.s    IL_001a
  }  // end handler
  IL_001a:  nop
  IL_001b:  ret
 } // end of method Program::Main
```

But it is still not clear what the `catch` keyword does in order to determine the type of exception that was thrown.

Comment: AFAIK, the exception is thrown using its specific type. Then, for each `catch(Type e)` block, it would be something like `e is Type`.

Comment: @AndreCalil: You can post this as the answer as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the CLR\C# spec?

Comment: I'm more curious what the code what look like. Specifically, how would the compiler implement this?

Comment: @frinkenstein789 It would be compiled just like a type test, such as `obj is Type`.

Comment: @frinkenstein789 A compiler targeting .net wouldn't need to do this because it's baked into the CLR. If you're interested in how the CLR does this, you could look at how the Mono project does it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just a short answer, a real one requires a book.  Exception handling in .NET is ridiculously complicated, involving many moving parts.  Including the native support for exceptions in Windows (SEH, Structured Exception Handling), one of the largest and most complicated chunks of code in the CLR (excep.cpp, 232KB of code), metadata in the assembly (which is why you don't see it taking any IL addresses) and the jitter.

Exceptions are raised by the *throw* keyword, it triggers the RaiseException() Windows api function at runtime.  Windows goes looking for code that's willing to handle the exception by running exception filters, registered by RtlAddFunctionTable().  Which are implemented in the CLR.  It in turns uses metadata that's generated by the jitter, tables of data that are built at just-in-time compile time when the jitter converts IL to machine code.  The jitter uses the metadata info that was added to the assembly metadata by directives like .try and catch, what you see in the disassembly.  The table data has info about what range of code represents the catch clause for a particular exception type.  Allowing the CLR to pick a location where execution should resume and tell Windows to move on with handling the exception.

Knowing where it started and knowing where to stop, Windows now starts unwinding stack frames, calling finally blocks where necessary.  Next, the instruction pointer it set at the first machine code instruction of the catch block.

Lots and lots of nasty little details beyond this.  Like the semantics of ThreadAbortException, the vb.net Catch When keyword, the complication of finally blocks raising exceptions, dealing with try blocks scope when SEH is purely stack frame based, the notion of uncatchable exceptions when threads need to be aborted.  The stuff that takes a book but nobody will ever write one because the reader will instantly fall asleep.

Exception handling in .NET is an iceberg filled with lead.  99% is under water, one of *the* most successful abstractions in the CLR.  Other than programmers using the catch keyword too often, that however doesn't have anything to do with the way it was implemented.

Comment: _The stuff that takes a book but nobody will ever write one because the reader will instantly fall asleep._ Just as I almost had while reading your answer. :) Nice answer, I was not aware error handling was so complex. Thanks!

Comment: Hans, as always, thanks for your wisdom. I knew my answer was absolutely simple anyway =)

Comment: Wow. Didn't know that exception was SO complicated. And regards the question I thought that CLR will use the `catch` block when `Exeption` could be casted to declared in `catch` block. In this case if the very first `catch` block was general `catch(Exception e)` it will always go there without reading what **other** `catch` block declare... but again - nice to know @HansPassant

Comment: *The stuff that takes a book but nobody will ever write one because the reader will instantly fall asleep.* That's a good book indeed; It will be very useful for me. Author could sell million copies just my naming the book as "Experts guide to sleep" rather than "Exception handling in .Net" :p

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer*: I hadn't read the CLR specs and I know that exceptions are far more complex than "normal" code. However, this is a very simple approach that I believe that would work.

1. When an exception is thrown, the code that's generating it will use a specific type, such as `IndexOutOfBounds` or `HttpException` rather than the base `Exception`
2. When an exception is caught inside a `try` block, the runtime will have a list of expected type of exceptions (that is, one for each `catch` block). Let's say that it would be `List<Type> TheseExceptionsMayOccur`
3. Finally, it would be something like

.

```
foreach(Type ExceptionType in TheseExceptionMayOccur)
{
    if(e is ExceptionType )
        //run the respective catch block
}
```